# Unable to create jar file through jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to create jar file, my code is in bitbucket and am trying to automate the job of creating docker image , but while run jenkins job to create docker image it shows an error in 'mvn clean package -DskipTests' stage

```
stage('MVN build'){

                 echo 'Creating Maven Build..'

                 sh 'mvn clean package -DskipTests'
                 sh 'cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/dch_docker_image_master/target/CKYC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .'
```

Expected result should be create jar file but it shows following error :

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.capiot.ckyc:CKYC:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 89, column 15
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------< [0;36mcom.capiot.ckyc:CKYC[0;1m >------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding CKYC 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;33mWARNING[m] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time:  0.385 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2019-05-09T12:26:15Z
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0.0: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0
[[1;31mERROR[m] [ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM org.apache.maven:maven-parent:27, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ org.apache.maven:maven-parent:27
[[1;31mERROR[m] [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar is missing. @
[[1;31mERROR[m] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

my pom.xml file is as follows :

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.capiot.ckyc</groupId>
<artifactId>CKYC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CKYC</name>
<description>CKYC</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.60</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.capiot.ckyc.CkycApplication</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>assemble-all</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: from the error in the logs posted above, it seems there is some problem with your `pom.xml` ? could you also post your `pom.xml` (preferably in a github gist ;) ) ?

Comment: paste  the pom.xml files under the error